# How do I search a Google spreadsheet using a Google API or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, api

I used Weebly to design a basic website where users enter data into a Google Form which saves the input into a Google Spreadsheet.
 I intended to use something like the below in PHP to search through the spreadsheet but realized that Weebly doesn't support PHP.
How can I work around this?

http://nowlookhear.co.uk/katiepiatt/exampledatabase.php